# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-idle, pyperclip

I've installed pyperclip and it works fine in python IDLE yet when I try to open the same program in vscode I get : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'. I'm on Python 3.10.0 and pyperclip is version 1.8.2

This is the program that I'm trying to run.

```
import pyperclip

print(pyperclip.paste())
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using a different Python Interpreter in VSCode. "pip install" will add to a global Python Interpreter, but you may not have that one selected in VScode.
Try opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) in VScode, start typing the **Python: Select Interpreter** command, select the command and then check which interpreter VScode is using.

Answer (score 0):

Check which python you are using in the IDLE:

[image]

And which python you are using in the VSCode:

[image]

If they are different, you can click the bottom-left to select the python interpreter:

[image]

Or you can install the package again in the environment which you have selected in the VSCode:

Comment: They have the same interpreter (Python 3.10.0 64 bit). I also tried reinstalling the package yet no luck. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @JoshinglyJosh What's the value of `import sys print(sys.executable)` and `pip show pyperclip`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to be working.

The problem could be because you are not working from a virtual environment.

1. Create a virtual environment. with this command. Before that, `ls` to the folder and run this command in the present working folder.

```
python3 -m venv "you virtual environment name"
```

2. Activate the virtual environment.

```
source "your virtual environment name>/bin/activate"
```

3. Install your modules here. Install `pyperclip` here.

This should resolve the issue.